# Fatal Error: Call To A Member Function Fetch_assoc() On Boolean

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to select only posts where authorId is only 1 and 2. And i do that like this:

```
$array = [1,2];
$array = implode(", ",$array);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE authorId = ({$array})";
$res = $con->query($sql);

while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'];
}
```

I got error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\blablaba.php on line blablaba
```

But when i try to get posts just from one author i dont get any error message. Actually it works, here is my code for one authorId:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE authorId = 1)";
$res = $con->query($sql);

while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'];
}
```

Comment: `WHERE authorId IN (1,2)` if you have a list of ids; `WHERE authorId = 1` if you have a single id

Comment: I think you query returns _false_ . Check your `$sql = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE authorId = ({$array})";`

Comment: @Mark Baker tnx i was try it before and its not working, but now working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this code:

```
$array = [1,2];
$array = implode(", ",$array);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE authorId = ({$array})";
```

raw sql query will be:

```
"SELECT * FROM post WHERE authorId = ('1, 2')"
```

First, you can change you query with using 'IN' operator:

```
"SELECT * FROM post WHERE authorId IN ({$array})"
```

raw query:

```
"SELECT * FROM post WHERE authorId IN ('1, 2')"
```

but, type of `IN ('1, 2')` is a string, when this may be list of integer values. You must convert this string to the set of char values with [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function:

```
CAST($array as CHAR);
```

and, now, find in this set with [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
 FIND_IN_SET(authorId, CAST($array as CHAR));
```

Final sql query will be:

```
"SELECT * FROM post WHERE FIND_IN_SET(authorId, CAST($array as CHAR));"
```

Raw query:

```
"SELECT * FROM post WHERE authorId IN (1, 2);"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [1,2];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE authorId IN (".implode(",",$array).")";
```